# Why TD is not expanding as expected?

Tags: html, css, html-table

We have a strange situation where in html table which is 100% and scrollable TBODY which is
100% width also, it is not expanding the way we want ONLY in situation when we have small amount of rows( so we dont need scrolling ).

Note: it is very important to me to work with %.

I have the same classes applied to all TDs and i expect to see all of them with same width.

The result is the following. http://jsfiddle.net/FqDfy/

```
<div id="pnlData">
    <table class="sortable filterable TF" id="htmlTabela" style="display: block;">
        <thead class="fixedContent">
            <tr class="fltrow">
                <td class="date-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt0_htmlTabela" ct="0" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="time-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt1_htmlTabela" ct="1" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="alarm-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt2_htmlTabela" ct="2" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="priority-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt3_htmlTabela" ct="3" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="stName-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt4_htmlTabela" ct="4" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="ptName-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt5_htmlTabela" ct="5" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="desc-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt6_htmlTabela" ct="6" class="flt">
                </td>
                <td class="zone-width">
                    <input type="text" id="flt7_htmlTabela" ct="7" class="flt">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable date-width" id="header-date" table-sortable="ignorecase">Date</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable time-width" id="cell-time" table-sortable="ignorecase">Time</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable alarm-width" id="cell-alarm" table-sortable="ignorecase">Alarm</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable priority-width" id="cell-priority" table-sortable="ignorecase">Priority</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class=" stName-width header-clickable" id="cell-stationName" table-sortable="ignorecase">StationName</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable ptName-width" id="cell-pointName" table-sortable="ignorecase">PointName</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable desc-width" id="cell-description" table-sortable="ignorecase">Description</th>
                <th align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#9E3232;border-color:White;border-width:0px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="header-clickable zone-width" id="cell-zname" table-sortable="ignorecase">Zone Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder0"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder1"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder2"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder3"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder4"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder5"> </th>
                <th class="fltHolder" id="fltHolder6"> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="scrollContent" style="height: 150.5px;">
            <tr style="color:Gold;">
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="date-width">13&nbsp;Sep&nbsp;2013</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="time-width">15:05:15.947000</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;text-align:center;" class="alarm-width">*</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;text-align:center;" class="priority-width">3</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="stName-width">SYS$</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="ptName-width">SCADA</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="desc-width">OmsLinesections&nbsp;&nbsp;file&nbsp;80&nbsp;percent&nbsp;full</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="zone-width" id="cell-zname">AllZones</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:Gold;">
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="date-width">12&nbsp;Sep&nbsp;2013</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="time-width">17:12:15.080000</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;text-align:center;" class="alarm-width">*</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;text-align:center;" class="priority-width">3</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="stName-width">SYS$</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="ptName-width">SCADA</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="desc-width">OmsLinesections&nbsp;&nbsp;file&nbsp;80&nbsp;percent&nbsp;full</td>
                <td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;" class="zone-width" id="cell-zname">AllZones</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @raam86 The body columns doesn't fit to the header columns. But Timmy, this happens even with multiple rows

Comment: You're setting `display: block` at least twice, what'd you expect from browsers? Also `align=center` is deprecated a lot. Please remove that.

Comment: If you want perfect control of width in tables, let them be tables (I mean, no `display: block`) and use `table-layout: fixed` algorithm. If you want cells (their widths) to adapt to content, then use `table-layout: auto` (that's the default)

Comment: The reason why display block is used is because we need to have FIXED HEADER and have Scrollable body, so i cannot remove display block.

Comment: But you can put all the rows to "DISPLAY: Table" which SOLVES my problem.

Comment: You should remove all the style attributes in favor of class ones. Example: 
<td style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:17px;text-align:center;" > 
should be something like 
<td class="the-td-class" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `tbody.scrollContent >tr
            {
                width:100%;
                display:table;
                }`
in your css

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with the below result then just remove all `display:block`..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are so many useless CSS classes and inline styling you should just start with a basic test case and work towards your goal.

Here is your table cleaned up for the most part. BTW the orange is difficult to read without a darker `background-color`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
.width_100 {width: 100%;}
table tfoot, table thead {background-color: #9E3232;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table tbody td {background-color: #bbb; color: #ffd700;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="width_100">
<thead>
<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Alarm</th><th>Priority</th><th>StationName</th><th>PointName</th><th>Description</th><th>Zone Name</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>13&nbsp;Sep&nbsp;2013</td><td>15:05:15.947000</td><td>*</td><td>3</td><td>SCADA</td><td>OmsLinesections&nbsp;&nbsp;file&nbsp;80&nbsp;percent&nbsp;full</td><td>AllZones</td></tr>
<tr><td>12&nbsp;Sep&nbsp;2013</td><td>17:12:15.080000</td><td>*</td><td>3</td><td>SYS$</td><td>SCADA</td><td>OmsLinesections&nbsp;&nbsp;file&nbsp;80&nbsp;percent&nbsp;full</td><td>AllZones</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Alarm</th><th>Priority</th><th>StationName</th><th>PointName</th><th>Description</th><th>Zone Name</th></tr></tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browsers add the tbody tag if it is not in Your code.
- This worked for me to make the tds extend fully within the table:

```
tbody { display:table;width:100% }
```